# How to select any 6 digit numbers separated with a dot on each line

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime 2 and I have a giant text file that is like:

```
12lk lkkls 92k.sk kal lk 123.456 ldfdk pak 1. s
193.482 ls k lsdk 2.w0 slk s099092 s,. s.
kllk aslk a01ma lka 983.873
```

Every line has only one number like XXX.XXX. I need to clean everything else but that number.
Can I do that using only Sublime and regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find required string in line, capture it and replace line with capturing string.

```
.*(\d{3}\.\d{3}).*
```

[regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/fC9wD4/1)

Answer (score 1):

`Find` > `Replace..`

```
Find What: ^.*(\d\d\d\.\d\d\d).*$
Replace With: \1
```